# iOS 11 Enterprise Ad-Hoc .ipa not installing until app is force quit

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

We have an Enterprise .ipa hosted on our server along with the proper .plist file to instruct iOS how to perform the install.

This has previously worked well to distribute app updates on devices iOS 10 and lower.. ie. user launches app, app checks .plist file on server for version, and if version is newer, app will openUrl to `"itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=%xxxxx.plist`. Upon agreeing to the system prompt "XYZ would like to install App", the app will quit and perform the update.

But for some reason on iOS 11 devices, when following the same process and prompting the user to install the update, nothing happens after accepting the prompt. From there, the app will not perform the install until the user force quits it.

My question is... is there something that changed in iOS 11 to Enterprise ad-hoc installs? And also.. is it acceptable to do something like `exit(0);` to force the app to quit after the user has accepted the update prompt?

Any and all help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Did you find a solution yet? Having the same issue.

Comment: @MarcusFranzenwe ended up just going with `exit(0);` upon user accepting the install prompt for iOS11 devices. No issues so far but definitely will revisit this and see if behavior changes in future versions of iOS.

Comment: I just had the same issue and had to "fix" it with `exit(0)` too. Have you found any changelog about this change on the Apple developer website? I couldn't find anything! That's unbelievable.

Comment: I am facing the same problem.. Is there any solution available to it yet? In my case, I have just created an OTA link which is working perfectly on all devices except iOS 11 devices.